# É recomendável usar mais de uma Activity em um projeto Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Eu sempre uso várias (em projeto grande com web service e tudo), o ideal é usar apenas uma ou não há problemas usar várias?

Comment: Não entendi qual problema fez você questionar o uso de várias *activities*. Afinal, [uma `Activity` é um componente que provê uma tela para interação dos usuários](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html), ou seja, em toda uma aplicação é provável sim que existam várias.

Comment: O que é recomendável é que uma *Activity* se foque em um só assunto/actividade.

Comment: É possível ter um aplicativo com uma `Activity` e vários `Fragments`, e isso pode lhe trazer vantagens em relação à abordagem com várias `Activities`.

Answer (score 1):

Usar mais de uma `Activity` é uma opção e não uma obrigação; com o advento dos `Fragments`, você pode ter um aplicativo com uma única `Activity` e vários `Fragments`, que seriam efetivamente as telas do seu aplicativo.

Como ouvi uma vez, a `Activity` seria o palco e os `Fragments` os atores.

Um aplicativo assim se comporta como um SPA (*Single Page Application*).

**Vantagens:**

- Suporte a layouts específicos para tablets;
- `AsyncTasks` não dependem do método obsoleto [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()) (ou de [coisa pior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730855/prevent-screen-rotation-android)) para que não sejam destruídas durante uma rotação de tela ou qualquer outra mudança de configuração;
- A *Action Bar* não é recriada a cada mudança de tela.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, normalmente cada Activity represta uma tela do projeto Android.

Answer (score 0):

Melhor usar uma activity para cada tela.Se voce usar métodos para inflar outro layout, estará levando a bagagem do layout anterior, como banco de dados aberto, teclado visível, etc. É boa prática uma Activity para cada Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar quantas activity forem necessarias para suas necessidades,o que acontece é que projetos muito grandes com várias telas exigem mais organização e controle dos processos.